# F12 failed to bring up boot menu

Tags: boot, menu

A while back, I tried without success to install dual boot OS ( windows 10 and Ubuntu)  on a single hard drive. To my surprise, I am not even able to bring up boot menu by pressing F12 ( or Fn+F12).
It eventually boots into Ubuntu. The the following is what parted shows:

```
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA ST1000DM010-2EP1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  135MB   134MB                   Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      135MB   948GB   948GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 3      948GB   968GB   20.0GB  ext4
 4      968GB   984GB   16.0GB  linux-swap(v1)
 5      984GB   985GB   900MB   fat32                                         boot, esp
 6      985GB   995GB   10.0GB  ext4
 7      995GB   1000GB  5529MB  ext4
```

I am seeking answers to following questions :

1. How to bring up boot menu?
2. How to boot into Windows ( from Windows 10 backup on USB stick )
3. How to modify the current partition table to allow dual boot?

Thanks and Happy New Year,
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a normal dual-boot configuration, you need to see the GRUB menu. In many Ubuntu installations, to bring up the GRUB menu, you need to hold down one of two keys, immediately after the computer's splash screen...

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> if you have an older BIOS computer

<kbd>ESC</kbd> if you have a newer UEFI computer

From the GRUB menu, you can select which OS to boot.

---

To make the GRUB menu appear without holding down any key, you need to modify `/etc/default/grub`.

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

Find the lines that say:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=none
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

And change it to:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

Then do:

`sudo update-grub`

---

2. without a hack, you can't boot a Windows 10 backup from a USB stick.
3. it looks like your 1TB disk is already configured for dual-boot. Not configured well, but configured.

**Update #1:**

With Dell tech support's help, (updated the firmware and Windows 10), and switched the monitor's HDMI cable from Intel Graphic card to Nvidia graphic card, I was finally able to see Dell Logo and F12 worked to bring up boot menu.

**Update #2:**

I deleted all partitions used by previously (wrongly) installed Ubuntu. This time, I had to add boot option of USB boot under UEFI (in BIOS), then booted from USB live stick (Ubuntu), created four partitions : ESP/SWAP/root/home, then Voila, Ubuntu is installed properly.

Comment: thanks for your response.  I tried both ways : Pressing ESC key and modifying /etc/default/grub and sudo update-grub. The boot menu still doesn't come up. Instead, it directly boot into Ubuntu.   When I press ESC or F12 or Fn+F12, the system just doesn't boot at all. (I have to power off and on to boot into Ubuntu )  Here is the current /ect/default/grub <pre>GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
</pre>

Comment: @franknj Are you able to enter the BIOS, probably with the F2 key?

Comment: I am not able enter BIOS via any keys ( F2, F10 or F12), worse, if I press any of those keys while system is booting up, it would boot at all. I have to release the F key and press power button to allow the computer to boot up. Now, amazingly, it booted to Windows 10 automatically. The only thing I did yesterday is run "boot repair" tool under Ubuntu to disable "secure boot". But it didn't work right after I ran "boot repair". Don't know why it started to work after one night :)  diskmgmt.msc shows one more ESP ( on Disk 1 partition 1), in addition to the ESP on Disk 0 partition 5.

Comment: Is this a laptop or desktop? You have TWO HDDs? It sounds like your computer has been messed up for quite some time. If you boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, is there a choice in the GRUB menu, to enter the BIOS?

Comment: it is a Dell server and I played with it 3 months back. Finally, with Dell tech support's help, ( updated the firmwire and Windonws 10), and switched the monitor's HDMI cable from Intel Graphic card to Navidia graphic card, I was finally able to see Dell Logo and F12 worked to bring up boot menu.

Comment: @franknj Thanks for the update. Are you now able to select OS via the GRUB menu, or do you still have to select via F12? I added your comment to my answer.

Comment: Hi, Heynnema, thanks for your follow up ( I am not familiar with this site, not sure how to directly reply to your comment. ). So, my apologies. Some updates :  1. Connecting monitor to HDMI port on Navidia graphic card makes the Dell Logo show up and F12 works to bring up boot menu.  ( switch back to Intel HDMI port doesn't work ).  2. With the help of F12, I tried twice to re-install Ubuntu from USB stick by standard installation and removing existing Ubuntu ( exactly same version ) , but it seems to further screw up. I can't boot from Ubuntu installed on hard drive.  contiue ..

Comment: --Continue from previous comment : ( after two attempts of re-installation of Ubuntu from USB stick), I can only boot into Ubuntu from USB Stick ).  By running parted tool, I found the /dev/sdb is gone ( used to host Windows loader ), and it is moved to /dev/sda3. I am still able to boot into Windows via F12.  The default boot sequence seems to be Ubuntu ( on harddrive ) first, which fails to boot into Ubuntu.

Comment: My recommendation would be to boot what you can, backup any important stuff, use `gparted` to install a new GPT partition table (this will wipe the drive), then install Windows FIRST, then install Ubuntu, and you should be fine. Don't do any fancy manual partitioning for /boot or /home or /whatever.

Comment: I will seriously consider your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Finally, it is solved. after I deleted all partitions used by previously (wrongly) installed Ubuntu. This time, I had to add boot option of USB boot under UEFI ( in BIOS), then booted from USB live stick ( Ubuntu), created four partitions : ESP/SWAP/root/home, then Voila, Ubuntu is installed properly.

Comment: I am willing to accept your answer. But not sure how. Instead, I vote up your answer ( it didn't show up as mu reputation score is too low :).

Comment: @franknj Just click the checkmark icon that appears to the left of my answer. Thanks!